# Backbone toJSON with model in model

Tags: backbone.js

`model.toJSON()` is a great way to send your model data to the template, but if you have a `model` `set` on the `model` (which i have a lot), it will only "flatten" the first layer of `attributes`. the `model`  i have `set` in the `attributes` is still a full `model`.

I would like to see `model.toJSON()` output the `attributes` of the current `model`, and all `model`s it holds in its `attributes`. (and also the `model`s in the `collection`s in the `model`s of the `model`s, etc).

anybody ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify(model)
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Asjc/1/

JSON.stringify will call toJSON on its own as it walks the data structure.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior

Comment: i am getting: `TypeError: cyclic object value`

Comment: i cannot share my models sadly, but if i create an empty model and set an empty model on it, your code does work. So there must be something in my models that prevent this.

Comment: Try cutting out code from your models. Maybe you have toJSON overrided somewhere? Or maybe you have reference from child to parent?